# Car won't start and makes loud grinding noise when attempting to start it, video attached

Tags: battery, starting, ignition, starter, grinding

2012 Infiniti G37x, Attempted to start it but it makes a loud grinding noise and doesn't start. The lights and the interior electricals are working. Haven't driven it in 2 weeks but it started just fine when I last drove it. What could the problem be? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Video Attached: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gi8Tot_FE7VOtIwNEREednywUG6uG1IM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You need to have your battery recharged or replaced. It doesn't have enough juice.